# Getting an error when trying to add buttons to toolbar

Tags: qgis, error, toolbar

recently I tried to add some geoprocessing tools as buttons to my toolbar as I use them quite often.

I found ou that there is the option to add buttons to tool bar under processing/options, but when I tick the box I get an error that says:

'Specified path does not exist'
C:/PROGRA`1/QGISLY1/apps\saga

I think there is an old reference to qgis Lyon (I'm using 2.18.3) and a typo with the '/'\'. Is there a workaround?